# How can i change assigned class value in c plus plus

Tags: c++

I have home class in my application and I want to create new instance like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class home{
public: 
    string address = "default path";
};


int main()
{
    home person1;
    person1.address = "path 1";

    // doing some filter and sorting 

    home person2 = person1;
    person2.address = "path after assignment";

     cout << person2.address <<  endl;
     cout << person1.address <<  endl;
}
```

In this case I want to change person 2 address:

```
// output : 
// person 2: path after assignment
// person 1: path 1
```

But it does not effect to `person1.address` and it is `path 1`.

How can I assign `person1` by reference to `person2` with this output?

```
// output : 
// person 2: path after assignment
// person 1: path after assignment
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: [no repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e725b0cc1621ee5)

Comment: if you want `person2` to be a reference to `person1` then ... well, use a reference, as in `home& person2 = person1;`

Comment: thank you , it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want person2 to be a reference to person 1 then replace:

```
home person2 = person1;
```

with

```
home& person2 = person1;
```